# How to set the radius of MPAndroidChart PieChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

MPAndroidChart has `setHoleRadius()` which changes the size of hole on a pie chart. But how do I change the radius of entire pie chart? Is this possible? If you have any pointers, please share.

Comment: what do you mean by `change the radius of entire pie chart` if you want to set width and height do it in android traditional way

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by changing your layout.

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
    android:id="@+id/pieChart"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />
```